# node.jsで複数行のSQLを書くとき、整形がうまくいかない

Tags: mysql, node.js, vscode

VScodeでnode.jsとMySQLを組み合わせて書く時に整形がうまくいきません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上の図のように長いSQL文を書く時に改行を入れたいのですが、改行を入れると下の図のようにエラーになって動かなくなってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

うまく整形するにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。
PHPとMySQLの組み合わせでは問題ないのですが。。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これはエディタの問題ではなく、文字列リテラルが複数行になるときの文法の問題です。ご提示のプログラムのような文字列リテラルの書き方は構文エラーであるため、エディタでの表示もご想定とは異なるものになっています。

Node.js において、シングルクォートで囲った文字列リテラルはその中で改行できません。改行が文字列リテラルより優先されます。プログラム中の改行を文字列中の改行として扱う場合は、バッククォートで囲います。

具体的には、以下のようにすると複数行の文字列リテラルになります。

```js
const str1 = `SELECT piyo
FROM example
WHERE pyon = 1`;

// 以下は行内で文字列リテラルが終わっていないため、構文エラーです。
/*
const str2 = 'SELECT piyo
FROM example
WHERE pyon =1';
*/
```

PHP においてはダブルクォートで囲った文字列リテラルの中で改行ができるため、今までエラーが出なかったのでしょう。

### 参考

- ["How do I do a multi-line string in node.js?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6220420/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- ["Multi-line strings in PHP"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9744192/5989200) -- Stack Overflow